# How to save image Formed in Response.Write

Tags: asp.net

Hi Iam generating an image using Response.Write in a web page, I want to save the image generated in a folder, help me doing it please.

`Response.Write("<img src='image/Black.gif'>")`

Answer (score 1):

`Dim Image As String Image="" For i=0 to 10

Image=Image &""

Next Response.Write(Image) `

An image will be displayed using this code, now the question is I want to save that as a single image in my folder(server side)

use a fileupload control

```
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
    //Save images into Images folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/"+filename));

if your image generated is a stream use Image class to convert it 

    Image.FromStream(yourstream);

to save it without upload control:
      Image.Save(Server.MapPath("Images/"+filename"));
```

`Dim Image As String
Image=""
For i=0 to 10

Image=Image &""

Next
Response.Write(Image)
`
An image will be displayed using this code, now the question is I want to save that as a single image in my folder(server side)

Comment: I want to save it as soon as it generated, I dont have an option to use a file upload control. I have tried to convert the string to an image using a function but it is showing the string as an image and not the actual image.

Comment: you want to save it on server side or client side?

Comment: I want to save it on Server side only.

Comment: so I add "to save it without upload control" in my answer is it ok?

Comment: `Dim Image As String
Image="<img src='image/white.png' />"
For i=0 to 10
 
Image=Image &"<img src='image/white.png' />" 
 
Next`

Comment: The mistake is that you don't have a stream but only a src in img balise? When you write Response.Write("<img src='image/Black.gif'>") it means that you have this image in your server folder (image) so can you explain where is you white.png ?

Comment: Yes, I do have a black line image and white line image named as black and white respectively, I use a For loop and in that based on a condition i change the src of image so as to form a barcode kind of image. Now I want the barcode image as a single image and to be saved in image folder.